# How do I fix this DIV sizing issue?

Tags: html, css

So in my web app each user-submitted listing has a preview DIV which contains four attributes associated with the submission -- the photo, the title, the price, and the category. Each of these preview DIVs needs to be the same width and height. The images are resized to a fixed width and height to fit within the div. However, when the title is too long it breaks to the next line making the DIV larger in height than the other preview DIVs. Here's an image:

[image]

The bottom half should look more like this:

[image]

I'm thinking that since both the title and category are on the left they should be in their own container div, with the price floated by itself to the right. Titles can be a maximum of 40 characters in length so basically I need to figure out the best way to accommodate for a variable amount of text, and maybe replace text which breaks to the next line with an ellipsis. How would I do this? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the following code that will add ellipsis (...) whenever the title is larger than it should:

```
.elem {
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.